# How to process directory first, then files and directories under it?

Tags: unix, find

On my Linux system, I've got into a situation where there are not write/execute permissions on directories on a mounted drive. As a result, I can't get into a directory before I open its permissions up. This happens every time I mount that drive. The mounting operation is done by a tool under its hood, so I doubt if could modify mount parameters to address this problem.

As a workaround, I am using this `find` command to modify permissions on directories. I use it repetitively, since it gets one more level of directories on each run.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 chmod a+wrx
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. I wonder if there is a `find` option that processes a directory first and then its contents - the opposite of `-depth|-d` option.

Any tips?

Comment: You should try asking it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
chmod +wrx /path/to/mounted/drive/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to investigate the mount options available for that particular file type (I'm guessing FAT/VFAT here, but it might be something else). Some file systems have mount options for overriding default permissions in some form or other... That would also avoid having to change all the permissions, which might have some effect when you put that file system back to whereever its original source is (is this a memory card from a camera or something or a USB stick, or .... ?)

Comment: This is a folder that Bitcasa client (bitcasa.com) mounts. This folder was initially created on a Mac before it broke. I used Bitcasa's Windows client to back up on Bitcasa. Now that the Linux client is available, I am using it on Linux, but having trouble with this one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to StarNamer at unix.stackexchange.com, here's something that worked great:

> Try:
>
> ```
> find . -type d -exec chmod a+rwx {} ';'
> ```
>
> This will cause find to execute the chmod before it tries to read the directory rather than trying to generate a list and feed it to xargs.

From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45907/22323